# Installed iterm2 and oh my zsh. Now almost all 'command not found' despite trying other thread solutions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm a newbie in programming but now have to use terminal a lot.
After having a brush with losing my .zshrc once before, I've been careful not to disrupt it but I installed iterm2 and oh my zsh and now almost no commands are working. I've been through all the links I could find to try trouble shoot it but i'm coming up bagels.

Context:

- Mac OS monterey 12.5 macbook air M1.
- default terminal was zsh
- Installed iterm2 and zsh according to this [tutorial.](https://www.robinwieruch.de/developer-setup/)
- My .zshrc file now looks like the default that is overwritten by oh my zsh (hence the issue as my paths are now gone).
- I've tried the following pages for help:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691055/after-installing-iterm2-and-ohmyzsh-many-of-my-terminal-commands-dont-work-any) which suggests that I copy across my ~/.bashrc which I don't have. or the other work around which I went through and tried all the suggestions in there to no avail. Brew wasn't working so I tried that again, tried to uninstall everything and even tried to 'pip-purge' but that wasn't a recognised command either.
2. The first thing I've been trying to run was jupyter so I'll use that as the reference point. which and where are pulling up nothing. Trying to install it again shows it is installed. trying jupyter --version or --path shows nothing. I even tried 'sudo' on one of the solutions and it said that sudo was an unrecognised command.

My current paths that I have tried to put into the .zshrc file are as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/itamar/Desktop/Dev/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/itamar/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/itamar/Library/Python/3.10/bin/jupyter"
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export ZSH="/Users/pierrethiollent/.oh-my-zsh"
```

I don't even mind if I have to nuke everything and start fresh but I don't know what will work short of reinstalled mac osx and even then I don't know if this will actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. solution found for those who have the same issue and are not migrating from bash to zsh.

Underneath your /.zshrc iterm2 or ohmyzsh will have backed up your previous path list to a file called '.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh' which will have your old paths. copied these into the zshrc file and it's working. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Finder, CMD+Shift+G for looking a specific file.

Then type ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh. A blurred file name 'zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh' will appear. Drag that find insides the terminal and run. You might get an error said permission denied, just add 'source' at the beginning and run again .